# How to display WordPress audio player in table

Tags: wordpress, html, audio, html-table

I tried to add default WordPress audio player in the normal HTML table. i want to display all the three below div in same line even in mobile devices. Any possible to do like this or any option to show only play button in audio player or using html5 audio player.

```
<table><tbody><tr>
<td><div>My audio</div></td>
<td><div>[audio src="http://cldup.com/uMFLx60B4V9/9j8WQE.mp3"]</div></td>
<td>Date</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your DIV

```
<div>[audio src="http://www.website.com/123.mp3"]</div>
```

with this HTML5 tag

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://www.website.com/your_file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks Pirate. Audio player is not responsive. In mobile device, only half player is visible. Any other idea?

Comment: The audio player is not responsive because the table is not responsive. Here the DIV is the child element for the table. Make your table responsive, the audio player will adjust accordingly